# How does online code editing work in a PLC?

Tags: arduino, plc

Some PLCs, such as Allen Bradley CompactLogix, allow "online" changes to be made to the running program on the PLC. These changes are (almost) instantly applied and don't require the PLC to be placed in stop mode or restarted, and don't affect the system's I/O.

I'm seeking to understand how this works internally because I'm interested in the possibility of implementing this feature on the Arduino platform. I realize each PLC vendor has their own implementation, but I'm looking for generic concepts.

Here are two ways I thought of, which could possibly work:

1. Place the new code in an entirely separate block of memory without disturbing the old code. Then once the new code is completely written, and the current scan is complete, update the instruction pointer to the start of this new code block.

Cons: programs are limited to a maximum of 50% of the device's program memory.

2. Pause the PLC's execution once the end of the current scan is reached. Write new code to the same program memory area as the old code.  Resume with instruction pointer at 0.

Cons: The device gets paused for the duration of the code update, which could take many ms depending on how the code is being transferred into the device.

**Thoughts about memory allocation:**

PLCs usually either have a fixed set of pre-defined memory addresses ("tags") available to the user, or all tags must be defined when the program is created. This eliminates the issue of dynamic memory allocation, thus allowing any version of the compiled program to point to the same data memory locations without the need to remap everything. This allows new code to reference the same data memory and continue running where the old code left off.

Comment: It's not just code. It's also all the data that informs the code of what's going on at the time. New code might have additional data items that have no known way to properly initialize them to "just work" even if the common data were copied correctly. (Or fewer, even?) So #1 sounds as though there is a lot more to it than just what you suggest (the 50% limit.)

Comment: @periblepsis variables will either point to specific locations in memory or be dynamically allocated. I suppose in PLC programming, this is the reason tags must be defined manually: so that they are always stored in a known location. This would allow both versions of code to reference the same memory locations and greatly simplify housekeeping.

Comment: PLC programs have several representations, and I think they are in some sense inter-convertible, into a sortof virtual machine. The rawest seeming form is the "Instruction List". See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131-3 .... If you wanted to do this yourself, you'd need to implement a simplified virtual machine. Most simply, a sequence of {operator, parameter_identifiers}, and an instruction pointer. Maybe a stack if you're feeling fancy. See also: Greenspun's 10th Rule

Comment: I would expect PLC code to be interpreted rather than compiled so I don’t think this is a difficult thing to implement. It’s a bunch of instruction blocks executed in a loop.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't think it's necessary or even advisable for a PLC to run an interpreter due to the limited hardware power. Much better performance could be attained by compiling the program for the PLC's specific hardware architecture.  The programming software could inject a scheduler and other necessary RTOS components before compilation.

Comment: Ryan, I think you're on the right track. The Logix processors allow creation of tags on the fly (which makes sense as they're tacked on to the end of the allocated memory) but you have to switch to Program Mode to delete tags - presumably because the tag memory has to be reorganised.

Comment: @RyanGriggs The one I wrote used compiler tools (lexx-yacc type tools) but emitted a byte code (stripping comments etc.) that was interpreted by run-time software (which happened to be written in assembly, it could have been C or whatever). Something like a linked list program structure could easily have ladder logic lines inserted or deleted.

Comment: @Transistor newer versions of Logix allow deleting tags in Run as long as they aren't referenced by the program. Perhaps this leaves a "hole" in the memory allocation?